# Conflicting Scripts

Tags: conflict, jquery

I've read the Jquery docs page on conflicting scripts. But i'm not really understanding it. As well, it's multiple .js files that are conflicting, and they have the same names to boot. (but they aren't the same within.)

I have a set of .js for a fisheye effect. Then i have another set of .js for draggable. Draggable won't work with the fisheye scripts, and vice versa.

```
These links are for the fisheye effect.

    <script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/ui_003.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/effects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/ui_002.js"></script>

These files are for draggable.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Draggable/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Draggable/ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Draggable/ui_002.js"></script>
```

From what i understand of what the doc said,

```
 File1.noConflict();

 // Use script File1 via File1(...)
 File1(document).ready(function(){
   File1("div").hide();
 });

 // Use script File2 with $(...), etc.
 $('someid').hide();
```

I'm not sure what to do with regards to the multiple files, I'm sure that speaks to how new i am to this.

*EDIT*

After looking online, i thought it would do me good to use a single jquery.1.3.2.js file, hosted by google. However, that didn't work. So it would seem my problem is that i need each of the scripts above for my effects to work, and this just seems wasteful to me. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why you need to include jQuery more than once. For example, the draggable plugin will work fine if you've already included jQuery further up on the page. The same goes for any UI scripts you're including.

Your script declarations will likely work better like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui_002.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="HandFan/ui_003.js"></script>
```

The draggable stuff should work fine without needing to have its own set of the same base libraries defined.

Given this might not be working for you, let's see if it's the jQuery files that are the problem at all.

The jQuery noConflict() method allows you to assign different variables to call jQuery instead of the very common $ symbol. See if the following works:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You can then use the letter j where you would ordinarily use $.  For example:

```
j('#myElement').draggable();
```

Comment: That's what i thought, but when i removed the "duplicates" they stopped working. When i looked at the contents of the files themselves, they were different. I got these scripts from various tutorials and demos online. So they were probably modified.